# Linux Server Won't Connect to internet

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have a Linux server that I use for a minecraft server. Ran flawlessly for the last two years. I usually shut it down when not using it because servers are expensive to run. Usually when I turn it back on everything works fine and I can SSH to it no problem. However about a week ago I turned it on, and I couldn't connect. I didn't have time to play with it until today.

I went and looked at my DHCP client list and found it was using a different local IP. All my ports and everything including server config are setup for it to run on 192.168.1.113 now on the client list its using 128. So I edited the /etc/network/interfaces file to use a static IP as 192.168.1.113, got no network response. So I set things back to the default in the interfaces file, after I realized my router had a DHCP reservation table. However now my server will not connect to the internet. I deleted the reservation and now the server wont even go back to its 128 connection. I want to know if there is some way that I can restore the default /interfaces file, which I DID NOT make a backup of.

The current contents are visually identical to what they were:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also try to set the default gateway address to your routers internal LAN ip address. Edit the `/etc/network/interfaces`file and add `gateway 192.168.1.254` under eth0 replacing 192.168.1.254 with your routers address.

Another option is to set a reservation on your router to assign the 192.168.1.113 address to your computer. Then you configure your computer to use DHCP:

`auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the the reserved IP address settings on the router are off. Can you confirm the MAC address of the interface that is connecting to the router is the same as what is in the IP reservation table?

Past that I would suggest experimenting with a static IP address on the setup like so:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.113
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.222.220
```

Note the `dns-nameservers` setting with the OpenDNS entries.